# building boost with clang 3.8 on windows

Tags: boost, clang++

From some Googling around it seems that clang's support for windows has been improving recently and boost's support for clang may also have improved.  But I'm fairly new to all this heavy-lifting compiler configuration stuff and new to boost, so I'm not sure what the current status really is.

I'm trying to run the command:

```
 b2 --build-dir=build toolset=clang --build-type=complete stage
```

as suggested in section 5.2.4 in [www.boost.org/.../getting_started/windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary).

This does work to some extent, but watching the logs being printed to screen I see a few worrying things:

- statements starting `clang-linux.compile.c++....` even though I am on windows.
- `12 warnings generated.` (or similar)  perhaps always these are `-Wunused-local-typedef`, but I'm not sure.
- `2 warnings and 8 errors generated` (or similar) surely if there are errors the build has failed?  How am I supposed to know which component of boost has not built properly and what can I do to fix this?

I'm not clear whether I need MSVC the compiler, Visual Stufio the IDE, and/or MinGW and whether I need to manually set flags to pass to the compiler?  Perhaps clang+boost is not ready for windows yet?

Ultimately I want to use `boost.python`, and at a later date maybe `boost.coroutine`.

Presumably if I want to use clang for my own projects I need to compile boost with clang too?

Comment: FYI. Microsoft just shipped experimental support for coroutine in VS 2015 Update 1. It's not going to be proprietary; they're tracking the ongoing standards work for C++1z.. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/30/coroutines-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
bootstrap --with-toolset=clang-win
b2 toolset=clang-win
```

Make sure that clang.exe is on your PATH.

Comment: I'm running the first command but getting "Failed to build Boost.build engine". When i check the log it says "Unknown toolset: vcunk", "Toolsets supported by this script are: borland, como, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, metrowerks, mingw,vc11, vc12, vc14, vc141, vc142"