# VS2019 + Clang could not open 'libboost_date_time-clangw10-mt-gd-x32-1_73.lib': no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, boost, clang, visual-studio-2019

I have a VS2019 project, using Boost 1_73_0 and Clang. I get a linker error about a missing boost library:

```
1>lld-link : error : could not open 'libboost_date_time-clangw10-mt-gd-x32-1_73.lib': no such file or directory
```

When I "installed" boost I simply unzipped the files in to a particular location.

I see this question mentioned setting the linker path:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042696/997112

But my Boost directory doesn't have a `<boost_path>\stage\lib` path, it only has `<boost_path\libs`

(I did set linker additional dependencies to this, but it didn't work)

This file does not appear to exist on my system. Am i supposed to compile Boost sources to use this library?

UPDATE: Why is this library needed? Only Boost library I am using is Interprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the boost library binaries for `clang` which are usually installed in the  `<boost_path>\stage\lib` path.  See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041534/building-boost-with-clang-3-8-on-windows) on how to build `boost` with `clang` on windows.

The reason why you need to build the `boost` libraries is because something in your program references the `boost` `date-time` library.

Comment: Thanks. The puzzling thing is, I am only using Boost Interprocess, no other boost.

Comment: In which case, `Boost Interprocess` must be using something in `boost date-time`.