# CMake cannot find Boost on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a very simple CMake file which works fine on linux, but on windows, it says that it cannot find boost (even though it seems to find it, as it says "found suitable version"). Here is the initial build file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(filecompare)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Boost 1.73.0 COMPONENTS program_options)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(filecompare filecompare.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(filecompare ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

CMake output:

```
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR program_options) (Required is at least version "1.73.0")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/repos/filecompare/cmake-build-debug
```

So it seems it cannot find the library on its own, so I added these lines above find_package:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/local/boost_1_73_0")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2")
```

Now it somehow seems to find the library, but doesn't, here is the output:

```
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options) (found suitable version "1.73.0", minimum required is "1.73.0")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/repos/filecompare/cmake-build-debug
```

I tried setting stuff like:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
SET(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_73_0/boost")
```

but that doesn't help either. So what am I doing wrong here? I'm using the clang-cl on CLion with VisualStudio 2019

Comment: What CMake version are you using ? 3.16.3? Then Boost version 1.73.0 is not known to your CMake version and you should try to add `set( Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.73.0 1.73)` before your `find_package(Boost ...)` call. Don't forget to delete the CMakeCache.txt file in the build directory before rerunning CMake.

Comment: @vre: This didn't solve it. I tried adding this, deleting my build directory. Still same output. The CMake version that I'm using is 3.17.3.

Comment: Add `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` before `find_package(Boost)` and run configuration again. Its output will contain information actual Boost libraries which are searched and search locations. Then compare this info with files you have in your Boost installation.

Comment: FYI: If you add `REQUIRED` keyword to `find_package` call, then CMake will automatically terminate if Boost is not found. So you could omit the check for `Boost_FOUND` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Boost_DEBUG helped: It seems that it tries different library names: Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-clangw10-mt-x64-1_73;boost_program_options-clangw10-mt-x64;boost_program_options-clangw10-mt;boost_program_options-vc6-mt-x64-1_73;boost_program_options-vc6-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc6-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x64-1_73;boost_program_options-mt-x64;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
The versions I have all have vc142 in them. How do I get library versions with vc6 or clangw10 in their names?

Comment: As you use Clang for compile your project, you need Boost compiled in the same way. Not sure where you can get ready-made Boost which is built by clang on Windows, but you may build Boost by yourself. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041534/building-boost-with-clang-3-8-on-windows) on this topic.

Comment: Did you build boost yourself? If this is the case, did you did and used `b2 ... install` you should be able to pass the directory provided as `--prefix` option as path hint to the config version of `find_package`. The `lib64-msvc-14.2` part in the path may be an indication that you did not do the install step or you use the build dir instead of the install dir.

Answer (score 2):

To my mind you have two different issues:

1. `CMake` does not know where to find `boost`.
2. You have not built the `boost` library binaries for `clang`.

The first issue is easy to solve and you nearly had got it right. For `CMake` to find `boost` you need to set: `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, `CMake` will generate `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` from these variables. I usually set them as environment variables; in your case they should be:

```
BOOST_ROOT C:/local/boost_1_73_0
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2
```

assuming that `lib64-msvc-14.2` is where you built the `boost` libraries with `clang`?!
Note: the library binaries (including dlls if built as shared) should be in a sub-directory of `lib64-msvc-14.2` named `lib`.

The second issue is that you need to build the `boost` libraries, specifically the `program_options` library, for `clang`.

I've only tried to build `boost` with `clang` once, and then I could only build 32 bit binaries, see [Building Boost with Clang “Failed to build Boost.build engine”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440722/building-boost-with-clang-failed-to-build-boost-build-engine/62445912#62445912). However, that was 18 months ago and things may have improved since then.

Be aware that I often use `boost` libraries built with `mingw` (`gcc`) on Windows and have issues with `CMake` not finding `boost` see: [cmake FindBoost not finding Boost libraries when building with MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943885/cmake-findboost-not-finding-boost-libraries-when-building-with-mingw-on-windows) I wouldn't be surprised if you have similar issues with `clang`. Many `C++` libraries and tools (including `CMake`) assume that if you're on Windows then you're using `Visual Studio`...

I recommend building with Visual Studio first, since you already have the Visual Studio 19 `boost` library binaries. I also recommend setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to 17, because you're pushing *everything* to the limit at the moment! :)

Comment: Another possible pitfall: In my project, I had `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON`, but my MSVC compiler triplet was set to `x86-windows` (without `-static`). cmake could find boost, but not the static libraries.